# Commerce: reading Stripe object in Craft Transaction model

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, order, stripe

I'm looking to add the credit card last four digits to my customer's frontend order history.  Stripe is the gateway.  The Stripe transaction object doesn't seem to be available in the Craft Transaction object (the documentation seems to be in line with this).

However, in the Commerce CP under Orders, I have see the full Stripe object in the Transactions box and it does have the last4 property that I'm looking for.

Is there any way to bring that info to the twig templates?